# (C# / Unity) pass generic type into Interface extension

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

I'm trying to create an interface to handle different types of input where one input class (`InputValue`) cannot be modified and the other (`GenericInputValue<T>`) can have different value types

essentially I need to pass the `GenericInputValue<T>` as the type for `IInputHandler<T>` (note: not the same `<T>`)

refer to this line in the code below:

```
public class JoystickInputHandler : MonoBehaviour, IInputHandler<GenericInputValue<???>>
```

what do i replace the `???` with?

```
public interface IInputHandler<in T>
{
    void OnMove(T value);
    void OnButton(T value);
}

// handles standard `InputValue` from Unity Input System
public class NormalInputHandler : MonoBehaviour : IInputHandler<InputValue>
{
    public void OnMove(InputValue value) {}
    public void OnButton(InputValue value) {}
}

// handles generic input values with different types
public class JoystickInputHandler : MonoBehaviour, IInputHandler<GenericInputValue<???>>
{
    // note: each method has a different value type
    public void OnMove(GenericInputValue<Vector2> value) {}
    public void OnButton(GenericInputValue<bool> value) {}
}

// stores a generic data value without object boxing
public class GenericInputValue<T>()
{
    private T value;
    public GenericInputValue(T value) { this.value = value };
    public T get() { return this.value; }
}
```

if I can only use `IInputHandler<GenericInputValue>` then `GenericInputValue` will need to box/unbox an `object` to store different types of data, which I'm trying to avoid
eg

```
public class GenericInputValue
{
    private object value;
    public GenericInputValue(object value) { this.value = value; }
    public T Get<T>() { return (T)this.value; }
}
```

thanks

Comment: `note: each method has a different value type` -> well then you can't use a generic ;) which is probably why [`InputValue`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.9/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputValue.html) exists .. `It exists so that action callback data can be represented as an object, can be reused, and shields the receiver from having to know about action callback specifics`

Comment: @derHugo I think you're probably right. 

Unity InputSystem's built-in `InputValue` needs methods like `value.Get<Vector2>();` for presumably the same reason.

I just wanted to check I wasn't missing something obvious.

thanks